# Casting issue in CSWClientDemo of geotoolkit

Tags: java

I tried  to test CSWClientDemo of geotoolkit but couldn't succeed.

Here is a casting problem:

```
  GetRecordsResponseType response = ((JAXBElement<GetRecordsResponseType>) um.unmarshal(is)).getValue();
```

The error I got is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.geotoolkit.ows.xml.v100.ExceptionReport cannot be cast to javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement
    at test.CSWClientDemo.main(CSWClientDemo.java:71)
```

(meanwhile, I imported  org.apache.sis.xml.MarshallerPool instead of org.geotoolkit.xml.MarshallerPool.  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably got en exception in response and not the `GetRecords` response as expected.

Therefore the casting fails.

- Check why your CSW service gives you an exception.
- Fix yout demo code to consider the exception as a result.